# How to force impersonation on SqlWorkflowInstanceStore

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

In WF4, how can I force SqlWorkflowInstanceStore to use impersonation? We have a deployment senario where the database server is on a different machine and when we call the execute method on the SqlWorkflowInstanceStore object we fail our sql authentication if we cant force it to impersonate a different user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a SQL Server login to your database and specify that login in your connection string. The SQL Server login can use a Windows Authenticated account that is already on the server, or a standard SQL Server account (i.e. the **sa** account for example, but don't use that one :p).